# Auto delete mails and meetings from certain people

Tags: vba, outlook

I get invitations for useless meetings. I want to delete mails from certain persons (certain email addresses) and associated meetings in calendar.

```vb
Public Sub delete_useless_meetings(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim xMtRequest As MeetingItem
Dim xAppointmentItem As AppointmentItem
Dim xMtResponse As MeetingItem
If Item.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
    Set xMtRequest = Item
    Set xAppointmentItem = xMtRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
    xMeeting.ReminderSet = False
    If VBA.LCase(xMeeting.SenderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail1@work.com") _
      Or VBA.LCase(xMeeting.SenderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail2@work.com") _
      Or VBA.LCase(xMeeting.SenderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail3@work.com") _
      Then
        Set xAppointmentItem = xMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
        xAppointmentItem.ReminderSet = False
        xMtRequest.Delete
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

In Outlook I go to

```
Rules  
-> Manage rules and alerts  
-> New Rule  
-> Apply rule on messages I receive  
-> which is a meeting invitation or update  
-> run a script
```

https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/

but meetings and mails are not being deleted.

Comment: You firstly need to see that the script is called. Sometimes, it is not called form `ThisOutlookSession`. Try placing it in a standard module and adapt the rule to call it from there. Place a first (testing) code line as `Debug.print Item. Subject & " - " & Now: exit sub`. Then edit the rule, go to all its four steps and in the last one check `Run this rule now on messages already  in "InBox"` and press `Finish`. Exiting, to not have problems with many such consecutive runs. You only need to check if the sub is called. You will test/debug it after this step. After that. check Immediate Window.

Comment: Try `Item as Object` rather than `Item as Outlook.MailItem`.

Comment: If you really need help you should frequently come here and send some feedback to people asking or suggesting something... Are you sure that events are enabled?

Comment: As I can see using `Debug.Print` in Immediate window the script doesn't execute. Not even simple code as `Public Sub func(Item As Outlook.MailItem) Debug.Print "xdxd" End Sub`. What do you mean as "events"? Rules I made without external scripts are working

Comment: Remove "which is a meeting invitation or update" from the rule. Change `Item as Outlook.MailItem` to `Item as Object`.

Comment: Firstly, did you enabled macros in Outlook? Can you run a simple testing sub  containing only a code line `Debug.print Date`? Does it return anything in Immediate Window? Events are automatically triggered on something changes in the Application environment. I asked about it to show you a different way (without any rule) to handle the problem...

Comment: I tested it and I didn't get any response in Immediate window. I enabled macros as said here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-macros-in-microsoft-365-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6 and still doesn't work

Comment: Do you have AnyDesk installed? If so and you accept a connection I can better understand what you do wrong, or what wrong happens in your installation...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend considering the "Move the item to folder" option and designating "Trash" as the destination folder during the initial rule creation step. This approach has proven to be quite efficient and practical in my workplace experience.

[image]

Comment: this will for sure delete the mail so I will not see it in my Inbox, but the meeting in Calendar will stay as it is and I will get notification before the meeting about it's start

Answer (score 0):

If this is your work account, most likely `MeetingItem.SenderEmailAddress` won't be an SMTP address, it will be an ugly looking EX type address. Either use `MeetingItem.SenderName` (which might not be unique enough) or hardcore the actual `EX` type address instead of `SMTP` - you can see it in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author): select the meeting request, click Item button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select the `SenderEmailAddress` property and copy its value.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Public Sub delete_useless_meetings(Item As Object)

    Dim xAppointmentItem As AppointmentItem
    
    If Item.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
        
        Debug.Print Item.senderEmailAddress
        
        If VBA.LCase(Item.senderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail1@work.com") _
          Or VBA.LCase(Item.senderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail2@work.com") _
          Or VBA.LCase(Item.senderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail3@work.com") Then
            
            Set xAppointmentItem = Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
            
            xAppointmentItem.Delete
            Item.Delete
            
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and I couldn't make  to see any print from `Debug.Print`, even after adding `Debug.Print` before `If` statement. It seems like it doesn't execute even if I force it for first use while creating rule

Answer (score 0):

Does not appear necessary here but the usual answer to a Run a Script rule question is to replace it with ItemAdd or NewMailEx.

In ThisOutlookSession.

```vb
Private WithEvents inboxItms As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set inboxItms = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItms_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    
    Dim xAppointmentItem As AppointmentItem
    
    If Item.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
        
        'If an EX type address no need to convert to SMTP
        Debug.Print Item.senderEmailAddress
        
        If VBA.LCase(Item.senderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail1@work.com") _
          Or VBA.LCase(Item.senderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail2@work.com") _
          Or VBA.LCase(Item.senderEmailAddress) = VBA.LCase("mail3@work.com") Then
            
            Set xAppointmentItem = Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
            
            xAppointmentItem.Delete
            Item.Delete
            
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```